# Convert DateTime Format to Tuesday, 03 May 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

In my asp.net page i want to display date in this format `Tuesday, 03 May 2016` but when i retrieve data from sql server its showing `3/05/2016 12:00:00 AM`

How to convert `3/05/2016 12:00:00 AM` - to - `Tuesday, 03 May 2016` in **C# Code Behind File**

Actually this is my code :

```
string strAccountCreatedDate = ds.Table[0].Rows[0]["AccountCreatedDate"].ToString();
```

strAccountCreatedDate = `3/05/2016 12:00:00 AM`
Now i want to Convert strAccountCreatedDate Format to `Tuesday, 03 May 2016` in through C# Coding

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Use `date.toString('FormatToBeConverted');`

Comment: please provide code so we can help in better way

Comment: Have you taken a look at [CSharp-examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) on datetime formats?

Comment: You can read at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03/05/2016 12:00:00 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newdate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMM yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(newdate);
```

Comment: Rahman : its not working as i expected i want to display `Tuesday, 3 May 2016` instead of `03/05/2016 12:00:00 AM` and your code is giving only `03/05/2016`

Comment: if you use the `dt` its a DateTime type so every time you use it it will show you the datetime format of your system DateTime, if you want to get `Tuesday, 3 May 2016` then you have to cast it to string, as I have done it in `newdate` varibale. The `newdate` should be your expected format. But only `dt` represent datetime not a specific format string.

Comment: you are welcome if its help you then consider it accepted and helpful so that others also find it helpful too, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You should go through this [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for conversion in any date format

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string date = String.Format("{0:dddd,dd MMM yyyy}", dt);
        Response.Write(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
string strAccountCreatedDate = ds.Table[0].Rows[0]["AccountCreatedDate"].ToString();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(strAccountCreatedDate);
string Formatteddate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMM yyyy");
```